# getting RGB values of every pixel of an QImage

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I try to get RGB values of every pixel of an image. But it seems like something doesn't work correctly.

```
self.img = QImage(self.fname[0]) 
self.img = self.img.convertToFormat(QImage.Format_Grayscale8)
for i in range(self.img.height()):
    for j in range(self.img.width()):
        print(self.img.pixel(i, j), end="   ")
    print("\n")
```

So my code gives me

> 4278650631   4278650631   4278650631   4278650631   12345   12345
>
> 4278650631   4294967295   4278650631   4278650631   12345   12345
>
> 4278650631   4278650631   4278650631   4278650631   12345   12345
>
> 4278650631   4294967295   4278453252   4278650631   12345   12345

for this picture (6x4 px):
[image]

The picture has 3 white pixels in the second row, but the values that I print are diffrent from the colors in the image. Plus the print output has strange 12345 for last two pixels in every row. So I can't convert the values to RGB. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try printing

```py
qRed(self.img.pixel(i, j))
qGreen(self.img.pixel(i, j))
qBlue(self.img.pixel(i, j))
```

Comment: now it gives me 7   7   7   7   0   0 /n   

7   255   7   7   0   0   /n

7   7   7   7   0   0   /n

7   255   4   7   0   0 /n still doesn't match the picture

Comment: @AndSolomin34 it may be easier to understand what is going on if you skipped the rescaling to grayscale step in your second line of code

Comment: and what's the problem with the rescaling to grayscale? :)

Comment: comparing what you think should happen with what the pixel values are - the more transformations in between, the bigger the chance for confusion.

Comment: what is the role of uploaded_img (this is not referenced later in the code)?

Comment: sorry, uploaded_img is a typo. And about transformations. The picture I posted is the result of the transformations. I'm trying to get RGB value of that exact picture

Comment: if we take 7 = black and 255=white, and you switch i with j your results match the picture pretty well...

Comment: @pygri Yes: `pixel()` requires a position in `x,y` coordinates - where `x` equates to the *width*, and `y` equates to the *height*. The code in the question has this backwards, so it tries to read some pixels at invalid coordinates. Unsurprisingly, this results in garbage values being printed for the last two columns. If you run the code in a console, Qt will probably show some warning messages for the out of range pixels.